# I am not able to use Unicode system in my Intellij IDE

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-escapes, java-18

Sir I am not able to use Unicode system in my Intellij IDE. I can't use copyright symbol in java 18 JDK. I get the Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number, \U00A9.

[image]

Comment: This was a recent bug that was supposed to have been fixed in the latest versions. Double check that you are using the latest version. As a workaround, I found I could paste characters into a comment on the line, then drag and drop into the code. I don’t remember if I had to drag into a pair of quotes, and then delete the quotes. All very annoying.

Comment: thanku so much sir for give me right information

Comment: [IDEA-291006](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006)

Answer (score 0):

I use the below version, and it works.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Community Edition)

Build #IC-221.6008.13, built on July 19, 2022
```

[image]